# Entity Framework Core SQLite - Simulate Eager Loading in test

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have a repository that loads my entity (`City`) and its related data (`PointsOfInterest`)

```
public City GetCity(int cityId, bool includePointsOfInterest)
{
    var city = _context.Cities.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == cityId);

    if (includePointsOfInterest)
    {
        _context.Entry(city)
            .Collection(x => x.PointsOfInterest)
            .Load();
    }

    return city;
}
```

To test this method, I decided to go with SQLLite InMemory, as I could test the Eager load functionality.

Setup of the context:

```
SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
connection.Open();

var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CityInfoContext>()
    .UseSqlite(connection)
    .Options;
var context = new CityInfoContext(options);

var cities = new List<City>()
{
    new City()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "New York City",
        Description = "The one with that big park.",
        PointsOfInterest = new List<PointOfInterest>()
        {
            new PointOfInterest()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Central Park",
                Description = "The most visited urban park in the United States."
            },
            new PointOfInterest()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Empire State Building",
                Description = "A 102-story skyscraper located in Midtown Manhattan."
            }
        }
    }
}

context.Cities.AddRange(cities);
context.SaveChanges();
```

But looks like the SQLite always load its related data, which makes sense, since it is already in memory. But since it is supposed to simulate a Relational Database, **is there a way to make it not load the related data automatically?**

If not, how can I effectively test it? Should I go for in disk SQLite for my repository tests?

(I'm using EF in memory provider to test code that depends on the `Repository`)

Comment: Can you share the code where you are testing this? EF does not eager load. There is something else which is causing data to be loaded.

Comment: I am experiencing the same effect. I will try out with a file based database instead of using `Datasource=:memory:`

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? Sadly it makes tests less reliable.

Comment: @Tjaart In our project, we use local SQL wrapped in a transaction. It was the best solution found at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing against the same instance of your context and the same `DbSet` collection you just inserted? If you are, the objects are there because you've just inserted them a step earlier, still in the graph.

Try querying your context like:

```
var c1 = context.Set<City>().AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault();
// assuming you have initialized the PointsOfInterest coll. in City.cs
Assert.Empty(c1.PointsOfInterest);
```

You can now apply the same access as `_context.Set<City>().AsQueryable()` in your repository.